# How to log into the IntelliJ IDEA Community Forum?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-hub

I want to ask a question in the IntelliJ IDEA Community Forum that is available at the following link:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users

However I can't log into it, although I have a working JetBrains Account and can log into https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ and into https://hub.jetbrains.com/

When I'm on the IntelliJ IDEA Community Forum it is shown as I'm not logged into it. I see the "SIGN IN" in the right top corner and if I click on it or on the "NEW POST" near it I'm just redirected into https://hub.jetbrains.com/ and if I return to the IntelliJ IDEA Community Forum again nothing is changed. I can't post new topics or new comments there.

Should I use some magic or this is a bug?

**Update:** This issue was fixed by JetBrains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've verified that Hub login to the community forums works without issues on our side. Checked with Chrome and Firefox browsers with both Google and JetBrains Account options on the Hub page. If you still have the problem, please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with more details (browser, OS, auth method used, etc).

Comment: Already contacted JetBrains support in that page. Did you test an account that has no JetBrains product bought?

Comment: I can't see any new support tickets under your name (Rostislav Krasny). It doesn't matter if you have any products.

Comment: There is no name field in that support form. Try to search for my email address or JetBrains account, both start with "rosti". The support request was submitted successfully: https://i.ibb.co/XtZJKWy/submitted.png

Comment: Subject in that request is: "Can't log into Communitiy Forum of IntelliJ IDEA"

Comment: There are 3 accounts starting with `rosti` and having the same `Rostislav Krasny` name in the system. They all have different e-mails. I don't see any ticket with `Can't log into Communitiy Forum of IntelliJ IDEA` subject in the system. If you didn't receive the confirmation e-mail with the ticket ID number, please submit a new one.

Comment: I see that you've fixed this issue somehow before I've submitted my second support request. Thanks!